# Split file based on a pattern with leading zeros

Tags: shell, scripting, awk

I have a book in text format. I would like to split the book into several files where each file contains a single chapter. Therefore I'm using the following command:

```
awk '/Chapter/{i++}{print > "chap"i}' "$f.txt"
```

where $f is just the variable in a for-loop. I notice however that the files are named:

```
chap1
chap9
chap11
```

Is their a way to add leading zeros? So the files are named:

```
chap001
chap009
chap011
```

I'm using `/bin/sh` as default shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

```
awk '/Chapter/{i=sprintf("%03d",i+1)}{print > "chap"i}' "$f.txt"
```

Comment: Yeah. This sure works, but I think you will agree this is not very elegant. I'm looking for a solution where one can simply add more zeros,... But it works!

Comment: @CommuSoft : Updted now , this should be fine...

Comment: Or, a minor variation with which you can pass the width as an arg to awk: `awk -v"w=3" '/Chapter/{print > "chap"sprintf("%0"w"d",++i)}'`

Comment: @Peter.O, more elegant to write `sprintf("%0*d", w, ++i)` -- "A * in place of
       either the width or prec specifications causes their values to be taken from the argument list"